# Cross Method Factorisation Setup Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering if there is someone who can help me create this diagram in latex using simple tikz or tables that I can easily use for my worksheet.
[image]

I tried using tabular but the arrows misaligned with the variables in the linear factors is there a way I can control where the arrows points. I have no clue as to how to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: There are many here who could. Show code of your approach and you’ll activate them.

Comment: There are different ways to solve this. Therefore it would be great if you could come up with some code that shows which approach you‘d prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the use of `TikZ` code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\longleftrightarrow$}}
\newcommand{\rb}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{$\longleftrightarrow$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
$(x-5)$ &             \\ \hline
$\mkern12mu\mathrlap{\ra}\rb$    & $-8x-5x=-13x$ \\ \hline
$(x-8)$ &             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this where the arrows always point to the variables in the brackets? I had done this previously but the cross arrows never matched up.

Comment: Sure. Have a look at nodes in the pgfmanual, tikz.dev .

Comment: @MsThanh I think yes of course.